# JSON getString() removes spaces from string?

Tags: java, android, json, getstring

I have the following JSON data :

```
{
    "customer": [
        {
            "cus_name": "ravi sharma",
            "cus_email": "sk@yahoo.com",
            "cus_pass": "pass",
            "cus_mob": "91111111",
            "cus_add": "new delhi India",
            "cus_pass_reset_ques": "What is your lucky no.?",
            "cus_pass_reset_ans": "987"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to get `cus_pass_reset_ques` key data from JSON, `getString()` removes the spaces in string.

```
try {

    JSONArray earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("customer");

    for (int i = 0; i < earthquakes.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

        String a = e.getString("cus_name");
        String b = e.getString("cus_email");
        String c = e.getString("cus_pass");
        String d = e.getString("cus_mob");
        String h = e.getString("cus_add");
        String f = e.getString("cus_pass_reset_ques");
        String g  = e.getString("cus_pass_reset_ans");                  

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
```

So how can I get the actual data as in above JSON.

---

This problem has been solved, thanks to - http://www.androidaspect.com/2013/05/android-json-parsing-tutorial.html

Comment: What JSON framework are you using? It doesn't make sense, that it removes the spaces.

Comment: Why don't you post some more of your code - it'll make it easier to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Java JSON - (http://json.org/java/)

Comment: What does `f` contain? `Whatisyourluckyno.?`?

Comment: If this is your real code it does not compile. You have two variables with the same name (`e`), within the same scope. On a side note, once the compile error is corrected, your code runs and 'extracts' the field with no issue (spaces are definitely ***not*** being removed from it).

Comment: The only mistake i see is that you have 2 variables called `e`

Comment: that was typing error...

Comment: @JB Nizet f contains 'Whatisyourluckyno.?' but I need 'What is your lucky no.?'

Answer (score 0):

It does that to minimize the number of bytes you send over the network.

use .toString(8) to keep them in, 8 is the number of spaces for each level of nesting.